# Try catch blocks in C++ dll's in MVS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, dll

I have a code which imports a dll and calls its functions several times. For certain inputs the dll function is throwing an exception, but for others it works fine. After studying a bit about exceptions in dll  [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/01/11/mixing-seh-and-c-exceptions.aspx) it seems that the runtime exceptions are not handled in case of dll's in a straightforward approach.

Here is my code

```
int main( void ) 
{ 
    WORD_DATABASE wd=parse_data();

    const char* WorkingDirPath="C:\\Users\\Koustav\\Dropbox\\Project\\July07_PT
    int UserID=1;
    DEVICE_INFO_T test= TOP_LEFT;

    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    //    MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Recog_Malayalam.dll"));
    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.pppppp

    if (hinstLib != NULL)


    { 



    f_funci init = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"abc");
    f_funci1 reco = (f_funci1)GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"xyz");
    // If the function address is valid, call the function.

    int a = init(WorkingDirPath,1,(DEVICE_INFO_T)1);


    for (int c3=0;c3<120;c3++)
    {   
        try{
            "<<wd.annotation_detail[c3].uni_val<<endl;
            for (int c4=0;c4<wd.annotation_detail[c3].stroke_count;c4++)
            {
                log_cl<<wd.annotation_detail[c3].stroke_labels[c4]-1<<" ";
            }
            log_cl<<"Actual Values"<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            //cout<<"Supplied stroke label"<<wd.annotation_detail[c3].stroke_labels[0]<<endl;
            int b=0;
            try{
                b = reco(wd.word_db[c3],wd.annotation_detail[c3].stroke_count,PLAIN,0,'\0',1);
            }
            catch(exception e){
                b=0;
                cout<<"try_catch_success"<<endl;
            }
            //cout<<"Supplied stroke label"<<wd.annotation_detail[c3].stroke_labels[0]<<endl;
            cout<<endl;


        }




        catch(exception e){
            cout<<"There is an exception"<<endl;
        }
    }
    fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 


} 


// If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 


    getch();
return 0;
```

}

I have used try catch blocks in the dll as well. the error is coming from the second function which is called multiple times.

I have changed the project properties as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951987/prevent-c-dll-exception-using-try-catch-internally). But I am still getting this error. (I have changed the properties of the project that creates the dll and also the one in which I call the dll)

[image: error]

Assuming I have no access to the dll , how can I fix this code? If impossible, is it possible if I can access the dll?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in your code? I mean are wd.word_db, annotation_detail ... vectors? Could you be stepping outside the range of one of these?

Comment: I have checked it multiple times. It seems fine. Say my assertion failure is because of what you mentioned. is there a way I can track the errors ?

Comment: If you press Retry when you hit this dialog the debugger will take you to the line that caused the problem. If you then step back on the call stack it should be easy to determine if the problem was in your code or the dll.

Answer (score 2):

Try-catch is for exceptions. This dialog box is for an assertion. Different beasts, virtually unrelated.

Comment: Is there a way I can bypass these assertion failures, the way try catch block do in exceptions?

Comment: You can't by pass exceptions either. `try catch` allows you to continue, but in general you can't say anything about the state of the program afterwards. The best advice after an undocumented exception would be to save the users work to a new file.

Comment: can I use a 'continue' in this assertion failures in some way? 
But how would I know the exact line within the DLL where this failure is happening?

Comment: @KoustavGhosal: check the call stack. But the assert message is quite clear: The DLL uses a `std::vector` but passes it an invalid index (i.e. past the end).

Comment: Thanks it got fixed. There was a variable which was declared const and it was used to index variable length arrays. Hence the error.